# Invoking series of commands in a new tab in cmder

Tags: tabs, cmder

**TLDR:**
I want to use something like -new_console:t:tabname to open a new named tab in cmder and then transfer focus/control to that tab so that the rest of the commands I'm sending from a Python script run in that console instead. Or, I want to rename a cmder tab from a script running in the console.

**DETAILS:**
I often have to execute a series of commands in cmder in order to test the latest code from our continuous integration environment. Because there are several applications I often have to have running at a time, it would be helpful for me to have the cmder tabs named according to which application they are running.

The only way I've found to set a tab name from within cmder (apart from manually with mouse clicks) is to do so with the -new_console:t:tab_name command. But that only runs the next command in the newly opened tab, and not all the things that come after it.

I kick off all my commands with a Python script that accepts parameters to let me control which application opens and how things behave. I'd like to do something like this:

```
os.system('pwd "-new-console:t:' + args.app + '"')
```

so that a new tab opens with the name of the app I'm about to invoke in it, starting with an indication of the present working directory. But then I'd like all the commands that follow from the Python script to be run in this new tab instead of in the tab used to kick off the Python script. This includes printing some flowerboxed comments, but also invoking a local application server that will continue running.

Is there any way to, as you create a new (named) tab in cmder, transfer focus to that tab so that all future commands run in that tab instead of the initiating tab? Alternately, is there any way from within a cmder console to rename the cmder tab it's running in? That would be just as good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking, but I found the answer.

In the bottom right corner is a hamburger stack. Click on that and select Settings. In General --> Tab bar, change the Console setting from the default %n to %s. Then the "title" command will change the tab name.